# How to insert records from one DB into another DB on a different server?

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I would like to take records from one a table in a SOURCE database and insert these records into a table in a DESTINATION database on a DIFFERENT server with different login credentials.

Could someone please provide points on how this can be done with Sybase TSQL? Or is this not possible?

Comment: I would use an ETL tool. In the Microsoft world, it is called SSIS, or Sql Server Integration Services. I don't know about sybase.

Comment: Sybase calls them Component Integration Servives (CIS).

Comment: Importing and exporting data with bcp    http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility56.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use proxy table as below:

```
exec sp_addserver 'SvrName', null, '[ip or hostname]:port'
exec sp_addexternlogin 'SvrName', LocalUserName, ExternalUserName, ExternalPassword

create proxy_table proxy_src_tab at 'SvrName.ExternalDb.db_owner.src_table'


insert into dest_tab
select column1,..., columnN from proxy_src_tab
```